# vs 2017 (15.9.9) makes an empty solution for asp.net core web application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I just installed VS 2015 (15.9.9) and wanted to create a new Asp.net core web application. 
The problem is that it makes an empty solution for me.
No projects in there...
And I can't add a new project to the solution.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Project templates are installed locally in C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\ -- look there to see if there are the project templates you are looking for. If they're missing, it is possible that you've not configured Visual Studio 2017 correctly.

On the top level menu bar of Visual Studio, click 'Tools', then 'Get Tools and Features..' This should open up Visual Studio Installer. Check to see if you've checked 'ASP.NET and web development' card.

In the Installer, there is a right hand panel that allows you to add 'Optional'  features to the various development 'workloads'. However, the default installation should give you the templates you're looking for.

Here is alink that might help: [Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.2#net-core-sdk-warnings)

Other than that, with the scant info you've provided, I can't offer anything else that might help.